# Variables defined but used in a class file & want to specify value in tex file

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

I'm new to TeX & I "inherited" a tex document & class file.  The class file has:

```
\newtoks\copyrtyr
\newtoks\acmcopyr
\newtoks\boilerplate
\def\CopyrightYear#1{\global\copyrtyr{#1}}
\def\crdata#1{\global\acmcopyr{#1}}
\def\permission#1{\global\boilerplate{#1}}
```

but it never uses any of `copyrtyr`, `acmcopyr`, `boilerplate`, `CopyrightYear`, `crdata`, or `permission`.  How can I use these inside a `\toappear{}` in the class file but specify the values in the tex file ?  All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Your question is a little bit difficult to understand. the last 3 lines are `setting` macros, i.e. they set the values of `\copyrtyr` etc.

Answer (score 2):

`\newtoks` defines a token register, i.e. a place to store tokens.

`\newtoks{\copyrtyr}` --> token register \copyrtyr is defined.

`\copyrtyr{2015}` will set the register to the value 2015. If this is to be used ('printed') later on, use `\the\copyrtyr` then --> `\the` is a `TeX` command sequence (almost) always forcing to print some value or state of a register.

The `\def\CopyrightYear#1` is a macro definition -> it will use the value enclosed in a `{...}` pair and store it to the token register `\copyrtyr` here (as such is the definition in the given code) --> all the other `\def` and `\newtoks` are quite similar then.

In the class you can define the command `\toappear` basically to be anything, e.g. print out the register values like here:

```
\newcommand{\toappear}{\the\copyrtyr\ \the\acmcopyr\ \the\boilerplate}
```

This definition is not a call (and the usefullness of `\toappear` at the moment is *doubtfull`;-)) --> it just says what`\toappear` should do if it is called later.

The call of `\CopyrightYear{2015}` could happen after `\begin{document}`, i.e. does not need to be in the preamble and it does not need to be in the class, unless some values should be given right from the start.

See also, that a reuse of `\CopyrightYear` etc. will change the output of `\toappear` later on, but not the previous one.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Suppose this is class content

\newtoks{\copyrtyr}
\newtoks{\acmcopyr}
\newtoks{\boilerplate}
\def\CopyrightYear#1{\global\copyrtyr{#1}}
\def\crdata#1{\global\acmcopyr{#1}}
\def\permission#1{\global\boilerplate{#1}}




\newcommand{\toappear}{\the\copyrtyr\ \the\acmcopyr\ \the\boilerplate}

%End of class content

% Now set the values of the token registers (can be done later on too)

\CopyrightYear{2015}
\crdata{Groucho Marx}
\permission{No copying allowed}


\begin{document}

% Call \toappear here or later on
\toappear

% Redefine the register contents
\CopyrightYear{2016}
\crdata{Harpo Marx}
\permission{All copying is allowed}


\toappear


\end{document}
```

[image]